# Calculate the 5 minutes ceiling

Tags: linux, bash, date, redhat

Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.2 (Maipo)

I want to round the time to the nearest 5 minutes, only up, not down, for example:

08:09:15 should be 08:10:00

08:11:26 should be 08:15:00

08:17:58 should be 08:20:00

I have been trying with:

```
(date -d @$(( (($(date +%s) + 150) / 300) * 300)) "+%H:%M:%S")
```

This will round the time but also down (08:11:18 will result in 08:10:00 and not 08:15:00)

Any idea how i can achieve this?

Comment: Change 150 to 299. What you add to the time is the threshold for rounding up. If you add 150, it rounds up if you're within 150 seconds of the 5-minute line. If  you add 299, it rounds up if you're within 299 seconds, which is always except when you're right on the previous line. Try it yourself on a piece of paper and convince yourself it works.

Comment: Adding `299` will round `'08:15:00'` to `'08:15:00'` but IMO it should become `'08:20:00'`

Comment: @jww i saw that post also, this will round up but in either way. I need to round up always to the above value, not below.

Comment: This questions sounds like a duplicate, but it is not. It is titled with "rounding", but the question asks for "ceiling". I have flagged to reopen.

Comment: Linked question is not really a dup as OP always wants to round up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this utility function for your rounding up:

```
roundDt() {
   local n=300
   local str="$1"
   date -d @$(( ($(date -d "$str" '+%s') + $n)/$n * $n)) '+%H:%M:%S'
}
```

**Then invoke this function as:**

```
roundDt '08:09:15'
08:10:00    

roundDt '08:11:26'
08:15:00

roundDt '08:17:58'
08:20:00
```

To trace how this function is computing use `-x` (trace mode) after exporting:

```
export -f roundDt

bash -cx "roundDt '08:11:26'"
```

```
+ roundDt 08:11:26
+ typeset n=300
+ typeset str=08:11:26
++ date -d 08:11:26 +%s
+ date -d @1535631300 +%H:%M:%S
08:15:00
```

Comment: Hi anubhava, if i want to use this function with the systime and store it in a variable, how can i achieve this?

Comment: To call it for systime and save in a variable use: `newdt=$(roundDt "$(date '+%H:%M:%S')")` and then do `echo $newdt"`

Answer (score 2):

GNU date can calculate already. It is explained in the manual in the chapter "[Relative items in date strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Relative-items-in-date-strings.html)". So you need just one `date` call.

```
d=$(date +%T)                             # get the current time
IFS=: read h m s <<< "$d"                 # parse it in hours, minutes and seconds
inc=$(( 300 - (m * 60 + s) % 300 ))       # calculate the seconds to increment
date -d "$d $inc sec" +%T                 # output the new time with the offset
```

Btw: `+%T` [is the same as](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Time-conversion-specifiers.html#Time-conversion-specifiers) `+%H:%M:%S`.